# Replace html_safe with content_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working on a pretty simple project. We have the following coming in for a post's content: "Here is some text".

Right now it looks like this in the view:

```
<%= raw @post.content %>
```

This works perfectly but it's failing in lint with a warning "Tagging a string as html safe may be a security risk, prefer 'safe_join' or other Rails tag helpers instead.

So I moved to using:

```
<%= @post.content.html_safe %>
```

Same lint warning. I tried using h @post.content but I get all the HTML crud.

So then I switched to:

```
<%= content_tag @post.content %>
```

Works except it displays the following: <"Here is some text">

So 1. Why is it displaying them? 2. How do I get rid of them? Is content_tag the best replacement for raw?

Comment: So `@post.content` is HTML that has already been scrubbed to remove unpleasant things and you need to get this known-to-be-clean HTML into the view while also keeping your lint tool from complaining?

Comment: Looks like applying raw to it is cleaning it and applying the HTML and applying content_tag is cleaning it but leaving "<" at the beginning of the content.

Comment: You use `content_tag` like `content_tag(:div, content)`, `content_tag(:p, content)`, `content_tag(:some_other_tag, ...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really an answer to why but in this situation using the following resolved the issue:

```
<%= sanitize @post.content %>
```

Comment: If you just use @post.content, sanitize will get called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

- `html_safe` and `raw` will NOT ESCAPE the string.
- NOT using either of the above WILL ESCAPE the string.

So.

```
<%= raw "<script>alert('hello world!')</script>" %>
```

and

```
<%= "<script>alert('hello world!')</script>".html_safe %>
```

... will pop-up a "hello world!' dialog box, and thus dangerous as they can write any script here or add DOM elements to the page.

Not using them, and just using `<%= %>` will escape the string, and is what you'd instead want:

```
<%= "<script>alert('hello world!')</script>" %>
```

... will show `&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;hello world!&#39;)&lt;/script&gt;` on the page instead of popping an alert box; and thus safe.

Comment: However if `post.content` actually contains DOM elements like `<p>` or `<br>` that you want to show on the page, then you'd want to `.sanitize` them, and then append an `.html_safe`. See [sanitize here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize)